# как сделать так, чтобы если сообщения автора находиться выше роли бота, то return?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы если сообщения автора находиться выше роли бота, то событие соответственно не работала, как сделать так? Вот мой код:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.author.top_role != bot.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith("текст"):
        channel = message.channel
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} текст")
        await message.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Вы, вроде как написали в комментариях под ответом к предыдущему вопросу, что этот вопрос для вас уже решен. В таком случае, вы можете самостоятельно написать и принять ответ.

Comment: да, я уже сделал код он работает, но в одном сервере почему то member принимается за user, хотя канал не приватный, наверное сервер приватный или я не знаю, в другом сервере где я админ, не user, то всё работает.